# Python deque extendleft with a tuple?

Tags: python

I have a `deque` with max length of 10.  Is is possible to `.extendleft` and add a tuple.  For example:

```
from collections import deque

x = deque(maxlen = 10)
z = [(1,4),(1,3),(2,5),(7,1),(6,4),(8,2),(9,1),(9,5),(7,3),(8,3)] 
for y in z:
    x.append(y)
print x
x.extendleft((6,7))
print x
```

Returns:

```
deque([(1, 4), (1, 3), (2, 5), (7, 1), (6, 4), (8, 2), (9, 1), (9, 5), (7, 3), (8, 3)], maxlen=10)
deque([7, 6, (1, 4), (1, 3), (2, 5), (7, 1), (6, 4), (8, 2), (9, 1), (9, 5)], maxlen=10)
```

I tried:
    pair = (6,7)
    x.extendleft(pair)
with the same results.

Answer (score 3):

```
In [7]: x.extendleft([(6,7)])

In [8]: x
Out[8]: deque([(6, 7), (1, 4), (1, 3), (2, 5), (7, 1), (6, 4), (8, 2), (9, 1), (9, 5), (7, 3)], maxlen=10)
```

or, simpler:

```
In [10]: x.appendleft((6, 7))
```